# Linux Command to display filename and its datetime

Tags: linux

I am trying to list the files in a directory along with date and time.

I tried using the below two commands:

```
ls
```

getting output as below:

```
abc.txt  testFile.txt
```

Then

```
ls -ltr
```

getting output as below:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxxxxx domain users 23 Aug 22 09:00 RCS
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxxxxx domain users  0 Sep 12 06:09 testFile.txt
```

I expect an output as:

```
Aug 22 09:00 RCS
Sep 12 06:09 testFile.txt
```

Comment: I think this question could better be asked at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Nota: your `23` in `23 Aug 22` is a ***size***!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below command to get the output as you needed :

```
ls -l|awk '{print $6,$7,$8,$9}'
```

We are using `-l` as long listing which will give you most of the information and then we will use `awk` command to fetch what we want. You can tweak the print statement as per your requirement.

Comment: Avoid useless forks, use appropriated command, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57901917/1765658

Comment: This won't work when filename contain spaces!

Comment: @Priya You're wrong, accepting this: this answer is buggy as they won't work when filenames do contain spaces! If you really want to use `ls`, use my `sed` command! (Then explain why using `ls` is important).

Comment: @F.Hauri Your answer was buggy for me whereas this worked

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [stat](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/stat.htm) command ?

`stat -c "%z %n" *`

or you can use [find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command with its "-printf" switch to get this :

`find -maxdepth 1 -type -f -printf '%t %f\n'`

Similar output can be fetched using the `find` command.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way we can obtain the result by using "ls" command?

Comment: As @Pacifist_AWS pointed out, you can pipe the output to other commands (`awk`, `cut`) to reformat and exclude things to get what you want if you really want to use `ls`. There's no single right way to get what you want.

Comment: @Priya .1: Thank for choosing this answer! .2: U could `man ls`;-) Then try: `ls -og|sed -re 's/\S*\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+//'`

Comment: small typo in your 2nd solution using find. should be
`find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%t %f\n'`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by F Hauri, it would be better to use a process substitution with `stat` and read from there, e.g.

```
while read time file;do 
    printf "%(%b %e %T)T %s\n" $time "$file"
done < <(stat -c '%Z %n' *)
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ while read time file;do 
    printf "%(%b %e %T)T %s\n" $time "$file"
done < <(stat -c '%Z %n' *)
Apr 12 15:36:38 comboboxfocus.c
Apr 12 15:36:38 comboboxfocus2.c
Nov  3 17:43:51 createonclick.c
Feb 28 19:01:54 cw-drawinput.c
Nov 28 07:08:19 debug.c
Apr 12 15:36:38 debugsig.c
Jun 20 16:35:32 evboxstruct.c
Jun 20 16:35:32 evboxstruct2.c
Aug 23 08:50:38 ex00-window.c
Aug 23 08:50:38 ex01-hello.c
Aug 23 08:50:38 ex02-packing.c
Aug 23 08:50:38 ex03-builder.c
Feb 28 19:01:54 exampleappmain.c
Feb 28 19:01:54 exampleappwin_final.c
Feb 28 19:01:54 exampleappwin_wsrch.c
Dec 11 03:56:00 examplewindow.c
Dec 16 10:11:15 file_dialog_new.c
Dec 11 03:56:00 infobarex.c
Dec  7 14:03:20 poppler_page.c
```

Either will work, but `awk` will likely be quite a bit faster.

Comment: This is very slow! Try this instead!! `while read time file;do printf "%(%b %e %T)T %s\n" $time "$file";done < <(stat -c '%Z %n' *)`

Comment: That is probably a better way to go about it, that eliminates stat and date within the loop. Yes, much better.

Comment: why ***probably***? Did you try them?

Comment: I did not downvote ***instead*** of providing helpful comments! I do both! Your initial solution was overkill, with **two** fork by output line!... Then you taked my **comment** but without any thank to them! Sorry.

Comment: I gave top billing on the first line. I always am the one looking to eliminate subshells, but here I originally posted to show and alternative that was much slower than awk. But your direction to use a process substitution on `stat` worked much nicer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## Intro

After reading all this thread, I think [rprakash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57901917/1765658) is the more accurate, as they point to two standard indicated command: `stat` and `find -maxdepth...`.

## Another way, using `ls | sed`

You could write:

```
ls -og|sed -re 's/\S*\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+//'
```

But as [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) could be very efficient and because I prefer to be able to choose time ouput format (`strftime`) as I want:

## Clean [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) way to list date and files:

based on [rprakash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57901917/1765658) `stat` command, with pretty formatting, as [David C. Rankin' purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57902032/1765658), but without useless forks:

Short oneliner:

```
while read tm fl;do printf "%(%b %e %T)T %s\n" $tm "$fl";done< <(stat -c %Z\ %n *)
```

More readable:

```
while read time file;do
    printf "%(%b %e %T)T %s\n" $time "$file"
done < <(
    stat -c '%Z %n' *
)
```

And if you want sorted list, you could add `sort` in this way:

```
while read time file;do
    printf "%(%b %e %T)T %s\n" $time "$file"
done < <(
    stat -c '%Z %n' * |
    sort -n
)
```

#### Some explanations:

From `man stat`:

> ```
>   %x     time of last access, human-readable
>   %X     time of last access, seconds since Epoch
>   %y     time of last data modification, human-readable
>   %Y     time of last data modification, seconds since Epoch
>   %z     time of last status change, human-readable
>   %Z     time of last status change, seconds since Epoch
> ```

From `man bash`

```
while read ... do; ... ; done < <(stat ... | sort ..)
```

> ```
> Process Substitution
>    Process  substitution  allows  a  process's  input or output to be referred to
>    using a filename.  It takes the form of <(list) or >(list).  The process  list
>    is  run  asynchronously,  and its input or output appears as a filename.  This
>    filename is passed as an argument to the current command as the result of  the
>    expansion.   If  the  >(list)  form  is used, writing to the file will provide
>    input for list.  If the <(list) form is used, the file passed as  an  argument
>    should  be  read  to  obtain the output of list.  Process substitution is sup‐
>    ported on systems that support named pipes (FIFOs) or the  /dev/fd  method  of
>    naming open files.
>
>    When  available, process substitution is performed simultaneously with parame‐
>    ter and variable expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.
> ```

```
printf "%(...)T" $UNIXTIME
```

> ```
>   printf [-v var] format [arguments]
>   ...
>          %(datefmt)T
>                 causes printf to output  the  date-time  string  resulting  from
>                 using  datefmt  as  a format string for strftime(3).  The corre‐
>                 sponding argument is an integer representing the number of  sec‐
>                 onds  since the epoch.  Two special argument values may be used:
>                 -1 represents the current time, and -2 represents the  time  the
>                 shell  was  invoked.   If  no  argument is specified, conversion
>                 behaves as if -1 had been given.  This is an  exception  to  the
>                 usual printf behavior.
> ```

Comment: @Priya Did you test my *oneliner* at top of this?

Comment: yeah i tried this and it worked. But i was looking for one liner command and without loops. The one that u shared above using "ls" worked.Thank you